# more variable from usera._meta.get_all_field_names() than in model

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I try to print in Template all variables from usera._meta.get_all_field_names(), it gives me 2 more than expected, and I don't know why.

Model:

```
class Clovek(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    ulice=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    cislo_popisne=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    mesto=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    psc=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    telefonni_cislo=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    zdravotni_pojistovna=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Output in template:

```
['cislo_popisne', 'id', 'mesto', 'psc', 'student', 'telefonni_cislo', 'ucitel', 'ulice', 'user', 'zdravotni_pojistovna']
```

Comment: I dont know what `ucitel` is doing here, but `id` is added automatically: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: ucitel and student is extra

Comment: can you check your database once ? May be you had those fields earlier, and never removed it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have another model (or models) with foreign keys to `Clovek` with reverse relation names `ucitel` and `student`.

[`get_all_field_names()` documentation](https://django-model-internals-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/get_all_field_names.html) is very clear about that:

> Returns a list of all field names that are possible for this model
>   (**including reverse relation names**)